# LayersWP Customizer White Blank Screen

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer

I see the following in the console within Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined
at new Display (codemirror.js?ver=1.5:185)
at new CodeMirror (codemirror.js?ver=1.5:72)
at Object.init (layers-devkit-customizer.js?ver=1.5:37)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (layers-devkit-customizer.js?ver=1.5:516)
at i (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,underscore,wp-a11y,wp-util,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-&load[]=ui-draggable,jquery-ui-droppable,backbone,wp-backbone,shortcode,utils,media-models,moxiejs,plupload,wp-plupload&ver=4.9.1:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,underscore,wp-a11y,wp-util,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-&load[]=ui-draggable,jquery-ui-droppable,backbone,wp-backbone,shortcode,utils,media-models,moxiejs,plupload,wp-plupload&ver=4.9.1:2)
at Function.ready (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,underscore,wp-a11y,wp-util,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-&load[]=ui-draggable,jquery-ui-droppable,backbone,wp-backbone,shortcode,utils,media-models,moxiejs,plupload,wp-plupload&ver=4.9.1:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,underscore,wp-a11y,wp-util,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,jquery-&load[]=ui-draggable,jquery-ui-droppable,backbone,wp-backbone,shortcode,utils,media-models,moxiejs,plupload,wp-plupload&ver=4.9.1:2)
```

Comment: code mirror not working is probably not the cause, but rather something happening after the fact. check page source / error logs for something more major and failing that try deactivating all plugins.

Comment: None of my plugins are activated any longer. The error above is as much information as Console or Network will show.

Comment: the "of undefined" part tends to indicate the element ID is not present on the page. if you have a blank screen the HTML output has probably died and so it would not be present... so I'm suggesting look for the *cause* of the output dying rather than the javascript which acts upon it later.

Comment: Please, please do not invent new tags, unless they are standing for commonly used concepts in WordPress. Thank you. :)